# Nested loops python value increment and retrieval and writing to file in tf-df

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops, tf-idf

I have been working on finding total tf-idf values of each files from a list of files. So far I've calculated tf-idf values of all words in each file (inside `for w in words`). Now I want to add the tf-idf value of each word which ultimately gives the tf-idf value for a particular file `f` and write the tf-idf value of a file to a text file. I am somewhat new in Python and i am experiencing some problem in doing so. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
for f in file_list:
  (some code)
     for w in words:
       (some code)
       tf_idf = tf_value * idf_value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total `tf_idf` for all words `w` in file `f`, then you can make the following simple changes:

```
for f in file_list:
    (some code) 
    tf_idf = 0 # (re)set value for new file
    for w in words:
        (some code)
        tf_idf += (tf_value * idf_value) # add to running total
    print tf_idf # total for file f
```

As for adding the results to a new file, start [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).